# Issue while Customizing Drag Image in Drag and Drop

Tags: html, angular, drag-and-drop

I  am stuck in doing a Drag and Drop in one of my WebPage.
Since the Drag Image has a limitation of being translucent.So, I have created a cloned Element for my Element.

```
this.test = e.target.cloneNode(true);
this.test.style.position = "absolute";
document.body.appendChild(this.test);
this.ng2DragDropService.dragImage = this.test;
```

After Creating the Element,I am moving my above created Element on drag Over with below Code:

```
  let mouseX = e.pageX;
  let mouseY = e.pageY;
    if (this.allowDrop(e)) {
        if (this.el.nativeElement.classList != undefined && this.el.nativeElement.classList != null)
            this.el.nativeElement.classList.add(this.dragOverClass);
            e = e || window.event;
                this.ng2DragDropService.dragImage.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
                this.ng2DragDropService.dragImage.style.left= mouseX + "px";
                this.ng2DragDropService.dragImage.style.top=  mouseY + "px";
        e.preventDefault();
}
}
```

Issue occurs when I drag the Element in above scenario as my Code does not goes in drop event.

However,if I comment out

```
this.ng2DragDropService.dragImage.style.top=  mouseY + "px";
```

line of code or use position other than top(like bottom,right) my drag drop works fine,but in that case positioning of Drag Image is not ,what I require.

Kindly guide or help,what I am doing wrong,as I already spent 2 days on this Issue Only.

P.S --> I am using tgis Drag and Drop in Angular 2.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may want to learn something about customize angular directive.

here is a popular resource: https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

and demo:
http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/